# how to get arguments of find command and print them out?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to list only folders which were not modified during last 30 days and print them.

```
  workspace_ts="/home/user/workspace"
    if [[ -n $(find $workspace_ts -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -30) ]];then
        echo -e "\t- It seems that [folder_name] wasn't modified during last 30 days"
    fi
```

how can I get arguments of find command and print them out?

Comment: just do the find with `-mtime +30`

Comment: it should be done with echo printout

Comment: `for i in $(find blah blah);do echo blah blah;done`

Comment: ok. that make sense. But e.g. find command gave me 2 folders (folder1, folder2) and I want to see 2 printouts like that:
bla-bla folder1
bla-bla folder2. So results of 'find' as parameters in echo.

Comment: @123, no. See [BashPitfall 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're doing is printing a message you can use the printf option as it is the most efficient and probably easiest way.

```
find /home/user/workspace -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -printf "\t- It seems that %p wasn't modified during last 30 day\n"
```

`%p` is the name of the file(with full path from directory find is run in)

`%f` if you just want the basename.

There are a lot of other useful things you can display with it as well which can be found under the printf section of the man page

Comment: thanks. it's maybe the most brief and very flexible script.)

Comment: Not so flexible, as this would work only on GNU `find`, so it won't work on Unix such as BSD or Mac/OSX, as `-printf` is not available.

Comment: @kenorb flexible != portable. It is very flexible provided that you have GNU find, which I'm guessing OP does as they have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loop for that, as you can execute command directly in `find` using `-exec`/`-execdir` parameter where your folder name is in `{}`, e.g.:

```
find /home/user/workspace -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -execdir echo "It seems that {} wasn't modified during last 30 days" ';'
```

which will print you name of folders. In case you need absolute paths, then change `-execdir` to `-exec`.

Above syntax will work for both BSD & GNU `find`, however with GNU the folder name will be prefixed with `./`. See: [Why the dot in find commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18119/21471) at Unix SE.

To follow the symbolic links, consider adding `-L`.

If you're interested in portability, check: [How to force GNU find to follow POSIX standard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250191/21471)

Comment: Might wanna use `-mtime +30`

Comment: also could be. But I think within a loop I can use $(basename $folder_name) for better printout. In this case, I don't know, but think that it's impossible.
yep. +30. but it is not a big deal))

Comment: @Wlodek For folder names, use `-execdir` (it's executed relatively in the parent folder), if you need full path, use `-exec` instead. You don't need `basename`.

Comment: @kenorb execdir will still have `./` before everything so there would still be a requirement for basename.

Comment: @123 Doesn't seems so. E.g. `find /etc -execdir echo "{}"  ';'` prints for me without `./`, unless GNU `find` behaves differently.

Comment: @kenorb Must do, prints the `./` for me but only from the directory it is in, so like one level

Comment: @123 Tested with GNU `find` (the same command), it's adding `./`, but doesn't happen for BSD `find`. So it's some implementation inconsistency. BSD `find` following the POSIX standard, so it should be more correct in this case.

Comment: Using GNU find is a bit of mess. Raised the following question: [How to force GNU find to follow POSIX standard?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250191/21471) as it seems both tools works completely different in terms of printing `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in in *for* loop:

```
workspace_ts="/home/user/workspace";
for folder_name in `find $workspace_ts -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30 -print`; do
  echo -e "\t- It seems that [$folder_name] wasn't modified during last 30 days";
done;
```

Comment: See [BashPitfall 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: @geirha - I agree with you. Besides, find command has brilliant -exec and -printf parameters which I've forgot about.